# phonegap local notification doesn't alert

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, localnotification

I'm using phonegap 3.3.0 and https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Phonegap-LocalNotification for my local notfication project

1.drag & drop both LocalNotification.h & .m into Xcode plugin

2.copied & linked cordova.localNotification.js in www folder

3.add feature tag in config.xml and use "local_timed" like function

it doesn't display error nor the local notification

Do I miss something ?

Comment: This question is not new, please first search for similars. Second why are you doing the manuals steps instead of using the cordova CLI to add plugins?

Comment: maybe because it is an old plugin not updated for cli?